# MariaDB REGEX with escaped characters

Tags: regex, mariadb, escaping

I am developing a photographic database where each image has a description which is fairly free-form. I want users to be able to search this database - initially I used LIKE %...% but that gives in many cases far too many matches - e.g search for cat may return category and other words. So I decided to use REGEXP with \b to match word boundaries which mostly works unless there are special characters.

In my test database I have records with the following text fragments:
`taken in Victoria by`
`taken in Melbourne (Victoria) by`
`taken in Melbourne (Victoria). This is`
`this is a Victorian monument`

If my search is
`LIKE %victoria%`
I get all 4 records as I expect - but that is probably not what a user wants.

If my search is
`REGEXP '\\bvictoria\\b'`
I get as expected the first 3 records only. So far so good - but I cannot control what my users look for - what if they want records 2 and 3 only? So I search for
`REGEXP '\\(victoria\\)'`
and I indeed get the two records I want. But if I then do
`REGEXP '\\b\\(victoria\\)\\b'`
I get nothing. And if try to allow for them looking for only the 3rd record (with a trailing . it also fails.
Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `|` syntax.

This will attempt to the match either of the patterns.

```
\bvictoria\b|\(victoria\)
```

*[Wikipedia – Regular expression – POSIX extended](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#POSIX_extended)*.

Comment: Thanks but I know exactly the text I want to search for - I do not need alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

Short gap solution:

- Use case insensitive collations on the table elements being searched

Medium solution:

- Use [MariaDB's full text indexes](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/full-text-index-overview/)

This will use `WHERE MATCH(textfield) AGAINST('victoria')` as a search criteria.

Partial offload solution:

[SphinxSE](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/about-sphinxse/) provides capabilities of a full text search into the MariaDB syntax. Its getting a little dated as [Sphinx](https://sphinxsearch.com/) has progressed significantly since abandoning development of SphinxSE.

Full Offload solutions:

You can get better full text search capabilities by using dedicated search engines like Sphinx, Solr, etc.

Comment: Thanks but again that seems to only match words, not the punctuation.  I am rapidly coming to the conclusion that I will have to ban punctuation from search terms!